# Ограничения на количество авторизаций пользователей в core api telegram

Tags: api, telegram, limits

Занимаюсь проработкой интеграции с api core telegram. Суть довольно простая: пользователь вводит свой номер телефона, ему отправляется соответствующий код на тг или по смс. После чего у него появляется возможность отправлять сообщения с нашего сервиса в телеграм по номеру телефона. При чтении документации и составлении прототипа упёрся в ограничения на количество отправляемых кодов пользователям (в телеге написано, что не больше 5, но можно расширить при этом как расширить не написано) и вообще по ошибке flood весьма размыто. Возможно кто-то занимался подобными решениями и может подсказать реализовать многопользовательскую авторизацию, не получая постоянно бан на 24 часа ??